# Programmatically determine when MacVim finishes editing a file

Tags: macos, bash, shell, vim, applescript

I want to write a script that opens a specified file with MacVim and then waits until the file is closed before continuing. My original idea was:

```
#!/bin/sh
file="some-file.txt"
mvim $file
cat $file | pbcopy
```

This opens the specified file with MacVim and immediately executes the next command. I've been thinking of something incredibly hackish with `lsof` but I was hoping there is a better way.

If this isn't possible with plain shell script, I'm open to ideas in anything else. (AppleScript, etc.)

Comment: Wondering whether `mvim` has `-f` switch. If I needed to achieve the same task with gvim I would have just replaced `gvim $file` with `gvim -f $file` in your script. But I do not know whether macvim supports this functionality.

Comment: It does actually. This is fantastic. I'm going to add this as an additional answer as it's even simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up an autocommand to execute the command when vim (or mvim) exits.  I tested with

```
$ mvim -c 'au VimLeave * !cat % | pbcopy' /tmp/bar.txt
```

It is a little shorter to use `pbcopy < %`.

Be careful of what you ask for.  You might change buffers, and <kbd>%</kbd> refers to the file when vim exits.  Maybe this would be safer:

```
$ mvim -c 'execute "au VimLeave * !pbcopy < " . expand("%")' /tmp/bar.txt
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. I had no idea you could do this with VimScript! ^_^

Answer (score 3):

MacVim has an option to not fork on startup:

```
-f  or  --nofork     Foreground: Don't fork when starting GUI
```

via `mvim --help`

For the above script, the following works:

```
#!/bin/sh
file="some-file.txt"
mvim --nofork $file
cat $file | pbcopy
```

GVim also has an identical option:

```
--nofork     Foreground. For the GUI version, Vim will not fork and
             detach from the shell it was started in.
```

via `man gvim`